# C++: Changing format output for a single output operation

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an exercise for a C++ course but I don't understand the provided code. The question is: It would be nice if we could change format for only a single value to be output such as shown by the following snippet

```
Form gen4(4);

void f(double d){
  Form sci8=gen4;
  sci.scientific().setprecision(8);
  std::cout << gen4(d) << " back to old options: "
  << d << std::endl;
}
```

gen4 should become some “kind of” operator that applies the output parameters to only that single output operation.

I understand what is asked and I understand how I could define a custom I/O manipulator like this:

```
Form gen4(4);

void f2(double d){
  Form sci8=gen4;
  sci8.scientific().setprecision(8);
  std::cout << sci8 << d << endl;
  // from now on, all output will use the format defined by sci8
  // (until changed again)
}
```

So I have 2 questions.

1. How does the first code snipped make sense? He calls the constructor of gen4 a second time with the argument d but how and why should a constructor be called a second time, even tough the object already exists?
2. How do I actually make such a custom I/O manipulator that only works for the next operation? It seems quite tricky to me and I have no idea/direction what I should do.

Comment: `Form` could provide `operator()(double)` returning an instance of some proxy class (say, `FormatDouble`) that stores the format parameters as well as the double value. `FormatDouble::operator<<` would then save current format settings, configure new ones, print the double value, and finally restore original settings. In this scenario, `gen4(d)` is a shorthand for `gen4.operator()(d)` (a call to overloaded `operator()`, not to a constructor, which indeed wouldn't make sense).

Comment: I was suspecting it could be the operator() but googling such things is difficult, because google strips special chars like (). Thanks for the comment, if you make it an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Another option is to have `Form::operator()(...)` write the correctly formatted value to a `stringstream`, and return the corresponding `string`. This is perhaps not as efficient as @IgorTandetnik's solution, on the other hand it might be more convenient.

Comment: Good practical solution, but I thing for the sake of this task, Igors solution makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here is my answer using the advice given in the comments:
form.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Form{
public:
  int prc, wdt, fmt;
  bool sci = false;
  Form(int p=6) : prc(p) {
    fmt=wdt=0;
  }
  Form& scientific() {
    sci = true;
    return *this;
  }
  Form& precision(int p) {
    prc=p;
    return *this;
  }
  Form& operator()(double d){
    std::ios::fmtflags f(std::cout.flags());
    if(sci){
      std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::scientific);
      std::cout.precision(prc);
    }
    std::cout << d;
    std::cout.flags(f);
    return *this;
  }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Form& f){
  return os;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "include/form.h"

Form gen4(4);

void f(double d){
  Form sci8=gen4;
  sci8.scientific().precision(8);
  std::cout << sci8(d) << " back to old options: " << d << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  // Task1
  f(64959.454243425);
  return 0;
}
```

gives the expected result:

```
6.49594542e+04 back to old options: 64959.454
```

Thanks to Igor Tandetnik